# subprocess.popen not working in apache with mod_wsgi 3.5

Tags: python, django, apache, subprocess

I have a function in my app that calls a `subprocess.popen` to call a .exe app that prints an Excel File using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library, when I start the server with `manage.py runserver` the call goes pretty well and my .exe does the job, but when I start apache server (even with administrator user), everything else except the subprocess part goes right, and it simply doesn't call the command.

I put some `Console.Write` in my exe to help me know where the problem is. When I run with django server, all goes right, but whith apache, Interop throws me this error:

```
Microsoft Excel no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'E://Documents/092647282000.xls'. Puede haber varios motivos:
\x07 El nombre o la ruta del archivo no existen.
\x07 Otro programa est\xa0 usando el archivo.
\x07 El libro que est\xa0 intentando guardar tiene el mismo nombre que otro libro que est\xa0 abierto en estos momentos.
```

Basically it says that the file cannot be found or another program is using it, or the book I am trying to save has the same name (but I am just opening it, not saving it). This doesn't happen with the builtin django `runserver` command

**How can I make apache run this system (console) command?**

```
args = []
args.append('ImprimirExcel.exe')
args.append(a)
args.append(self.impresora)
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True,
close_fds=False)
(stdout_txt, stderr_txt) = proc.communicate("")
proc.wait()
logging.error('%d %s %s' % (proc.returncode, stdout_txt,
stderr_txt))
logging.error(args)
```

Notes:

I am using `logging.error` to make XAMPP saves this messages in the error log (easier to access).

I am using Windows 8 with XAMPP

I use python 2.7, Django 1.7 and apache with Xampp (Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.8 PHP/5.5.6)

This is my httpd.conf

```
...
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
...
WSGIScriptAlias /App "E:/Documents/App/App/App/wsgi.py"

Alias /media "E:/Documents/App/App/media"
Alias /static "E:/Documents/App/App/static"

<Directory "E:/Documents/App/App/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "E:/Documents/App/App/media">
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "E:/Documents/App/App">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Have you tried fixing permissions so that the web server has access to the file?

Comment: the file is created by the server app, but the folder has "Full Control" to "Everyone" (I did this to test) so there are no permissions problem :(

Comment: @Alex Have you resolved it? I am also in same situation. I hope someone provides me some guidance here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44316733/running-ssh-script-using-django-and-apache-server

Answer (score 0):

stdout=PIPE use stdout of parent process (ie wsgi module), but in this case, it is closed.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIRestrictStdout

Comment: Version 3.5 of mod_wsgi does not close stdout. Writing data to it should still work.